# How to use Airflow for orchestrating tasks on multiple PCs in the same server?

Tags: python, server, airflow, airflow-scheduler

In my office, we have a few Windows computers executing different batch tasks every day.

I'm working in the financial field, so, for example, our Bloomberg terminal has some tasks that can't be assigned to another computer (e.g. downloading some price data) because we need its software for running the Bloomberg Python API.

At the moment, I'm using Windows scheduler on local for managing the tasks of each machine, but I'm interested in Airflow: I would like to use it as a unique orchestrator. Nothing fancy, nothing complex, I just need to use the GUI for monitoring all the tasks of all our computers without switching monitor every time.

I'm just a beginner so I'm quite confused about the possibility of connecting different machines under the same Airflow "account": is it possible to do so?
How can I connect the different computers?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't think this is something for what you get a complete answer on SO, but a high level process could be the following: Install an SSH server on every Windows machine running a batch task, install Airflow on some Linux machine or in Docker, write a DAG that uses [SSHOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-ssh/stable/_api/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh/index.html) to connect to the Windows machines and execute the batch tasks. You can then monitor and manage the workflow from the Airflow UI.